# How to pass a class as an function argument in scala?

Tags: scala

The problem is the following:

There is a module with such function

```
def testExceptions(toTest: MyClass): Unit = { 
    val isException = try {
          toTest.increaseValue(-200);
          false
    } catch {
          case e: Exception => true
    }
    if (isException) { 
          // some actions
    } else {
          // another actions
    }
}
```

This function is importing in the file where `MyClass` is defined. It has such view

```
class MyClass(var value: Int) {
    def show(): Unit = {
          println(s"Value: $value")
    }
    def increaseValue(dv:Int): Unit = {
          if(dv <= 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException }
          else { value += dv }
    }
}
```

But I cannot pass `MyClass` object to the module function `testExceptions` because it is undefined in the file where this function exists. If I define MyClass in this file, it will be used in the `testExceptions`.

I will be grateful any help solving my confusion.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Please add the class-related code of testExceptions including their imports and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

> How to pass a class as an function argument in scala?

You can't. You can only pass objects as arguments. Classes are not objects, classes are *types*.

You *can* use reflection to get a proxy object that *represents* a type and pass that as an argument, though.

> But I cannot pass `MyClass` object […]

That is because `MyClass` is *not* an object, it is a *class*. You cannot pass a class or any other type as an argument, only objects.

> to the module function `testExceptions`

Note that `testExceptions` is defined to take an argument that is a *value of type `MyClass`*, it *does* not take `MyClass` itself as an argument. You need to instantiate an object of `MyClass` and pass *that* as an argument.